# How convert nvarchar2 between Oracle and SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

In my SQL server I run

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', CONCAT('A',convert(nvarchar,123),'456')) as mycol
```

and get

```
0xC2E6DDD93A5E4A4FEC8162D4847BD3AA
```

In Oracle I run

```
select standard_hash(concat('A',concat(cast('123' as nvarchar2(255)),'456')), 'MD5') from dual;
```

but I get

```
0x687A57C778D4AC73D90F1EB9290ED283
```

What do I wrong in Oracle. I want to have the same output!

Comment: You Oracle code is the equivalent of `select standard_hash(N'313@12', 'MD5') from dual;` and concatenating an empty string is pointless as empty strings and `NULL` are identical in Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joel has explained the issue, but as a variation - and because [Oracle discourages the use of the CONVERT function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CONVERT.html) - you can use [the `UTL_I18N` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_I18N.html#GUID-D162974D-09FD-429D-9E98-F357A29CBDB4) to do the conversion instead:

```
standard_hash(utl_i18n.string_to_raw(n'A123456', 'AL16UTF16LE'), 'MD5')
```

This incorporates MTO's comment about simplifying the value. It also assumes your database's national character set is AL16UTF16, but that seems to be the case from the result you got originally.

You can continue to build up the value if you need to - perhaps the `'123'` string is coming from a table? - but the concatenation operator is easier to use than nested `concat()` function calls:

```
select standard_hash(
  utl_i18n.string_to_raw('A' || cast('123' as nvarchar2(255)) || '456', 'AL16UTF16LE'),
  'MD5') as result
from dual;
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 0xC2E6DDD93A5E4A4FEC8162D4847BD3AA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8k4c1P1k)

Answer (score 2):

The md5 algorithm doesn't understand strings; it only operates on byte arrays. Therefore the exact byte encoding of the string input matters, because even a single bit difference will completely change the hash output.

In this case, both databases already encode strings as UTF-16, but again: the precise details matter here. [The specific difference between Oracle and SQL Server is Endian-ness](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229163/5469), with SQL Server using Little Endian encoding while Oracle uses Big Endian encoding. You'll need to change the Oracle query so it produces a string with the same Little Endian encoding as SQL Server.

I think this expression should do the job:

```
standard_hash(convert(concat('A',concat(cast('123' as nvarchar2(255)),'456')),'AL16UTF16LE'), 'MD5')
```

You can see it work on the sample input here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/oxEdqTYa

However, this stuff can be tricky, and you should test it on a wider variety of possible inputs with a few different character types covering more of what might be included in your live data.